# Is this a correct approach to weighting algorithm in a math equation?

Tags: algorithms, matrix-equations, mathematical-modeling

I have a list of products and each product is connected to another. Each connection strength_level ranges from 1 to 10.

```
Product A to B strength_level=7
Product A to c strength_level=8
Product B to A strength_level=2
Product B to C strength_level=2
Product C to A strength_level=4
Product C to B strength_level=3
```

I want to convert this code to an equation. My code:

```
Foreach(products as product){
   // strength variables
   $outwardTotal = 0;
   $inwardTotal= 0;

   // Get in and out connections
      $connectionToOthers = [sqlArray]
      $connectionToMe = [sqlArray]

   // Loop through all connections from this to other
   Foreach($connectionToOthers as $outward){
        $outwardTotal = $outwardTotal+ $outward['strength_level'] + 4;
   }
   // Loop through all connections fromt other product to this 
   Foreach($connectionToMe as $inwards){
        $inwardTotal= $inwardTotal+ $inwards['strength_level'] + 1;
   }
    $outwardAvg = $outwardTotal/COUNT($connectionToOthers);
    $inwardAvg= $inwardTotal/COUNT($connectionToMe);
}

   $final_strength = ($outwardAvg + $inwardAvg)/(COUNT($connectionToOthers) + COUNT($connectionToMe));
```

I have attempted the following:https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGNRw.png
 where **c** is number of products, **n** outward connections and **m** is for inward connections and **S** is the strength of the connection.

Comment: I have no idea what You are really asking, in Your formula $strength=\sum_{i=1}...$, the summation index $i$ doesn't occur in the summands, is this on purpose?

Comment: It's not clear what you are after here.  Why not show the calculation by hand in one case?  With your data $A$ is related to $(B,C)$ by $(7,8)$, no?  So...what's the answer in that case?  Or do you need more data than that to get the answer you want?

Comment: Very unclear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PeterMelech and lulu ... basically I am trying to learn how to convert the provided code to an equation... where I loop through products then inside every loop i do two loops... so for example strength of A to (B,C) would be 6.5 as  A = (((7+8)+constant4)+((2+4)+constant1))/4totalconnections

Comment: @naslundx I want to convert the code to an equation